# Why Teamviewer keeps running in the background?

Tags: teamviewer

After i installed TeamViewer 8 on Ubuntu 12.10, i noticed a running process under the name of 'teamviewerd', more specifically:

```
/opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/teamviewerd -f
/opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/wine/bin/wineserver
```

and it auto-reopens whenever i try to kill it and i wonder why this happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used the debian installer.
Even the "killall" doesn't close "teamviewerd" process.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Because that is the nature of teamviewer: it is build to respawn.

`/opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/script/teamviewerd.sysv`
is probably responsible for it.

To stop teamviewer use:

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon stop
```

It will show ...

```
initctl stop teamviewerd
teamviewerd stop/waiting
```

and it is gone ...

```
rinzwind@discworld:/opt/teamviewer8/tv_bin/script$ ps -ef|grep teamviewer
rinzwind 12712 12428  0 18:11 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto teamviewer
```

Commands to manipulate the daemon:

```
teamviewer --daemon status        show current status of the TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon start         start TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon stop          stop  TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon restart       stop/start TeamViewer daemon
teamviewer --daemon disable       disable TeamViewer daemon - don't start daemon on system startup
teamviewer --daemon enable        enable TeamViewer daemon - start daemon on system startup (default)
```

---

Regarding comment:

From teamviewer 9 help:

```
$teamviewer --help

 TeamViewer                      9.0.32150 

 teamviewer                      start TeamViewer user interface (if not running) 

 teamviewer --help               print this help screen 
 teamviewer --version            print version information 
 teamviewer --info               print version, status, id 
 teamviewer --ziplog             create a zip containing all teamviewer logs (useful when contacting support) 

 teamviewer --passwd [PASSWD]    set a password (useful when installing remote (ssh) 

 teamviewer --daemon status      show current status of the TeamViewer daemon 
 teamviewer --daemon start       start      TeamViewer daemon 
 teamviewer --daemon stop        stop       TeamViewer daemon 
 teamviewer --daemon restart     stop/start TeamViewer daemon 
 teamviewer --daemon disable     disable    TeamViewer daemon - don't start daemon on system startup 
 teamviewer --daemon enable      enable     TeamViewer daemon - start daemon on system startup (default)
```

Options are still there in TV9.

Comment: Yep so if you don't want team viewer auto starting use: teamviewer --daemon disable. Doing this mean that next time execute teamviewer you will get a message that says that you need first start the daemon and will also conveniently provide you with the command to do just that.

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore with the new version (9) of Teamviewer

Comment: @Frodik yes it does.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, not in my case and other users might have problems as well. The only thing which worked for me was `killall -9 teamviewerd`

Comment: On Ubuntu it does:

sudo service teamviewerd.sysv stop

Comment: for latest versions of Teamviewer  it is `daemon stop` (without leading `--`)

Comment: I use version 14 and this answer works

Comment: This answer is still relevant for Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa and Teamviewer 15.9.5.
My personal preference is to use native commands though. I've used `systemctl disable teamviewerd.service` to disable autostart on boot. And I use `systemctl start/stop teamviewerd.service` before/after using the app.

Comment: `sudo teamviewer daemon disable`

Answer (score 6):

```
systemctl stop teamviewerd.service
systemctl disable teamviewerd.service
```

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question it is not quite clear what those commands do. Please elaborate your answer adding explanations.

Comment: This is a nice **short answer**, but not the Stackexchange style ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you install Teamviewer 10 from the .deb file, `--daemon stop` as recommended above won't work in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (and others?).  Don't know why.

The daemon is an 'upstart' job, so it gets controlled from `/etc/init/teamviewerd.conf` not `/etc/init.d`.

Unfortunately, for me, both `initctl stop teamviewerd` and `service teamviewerd stop` result in:

```
initctl: Unknown instance:
```

`teamviewerd.sysv` gets installed in /opt.  So, to stop it, you need to do:

```
$ sudo /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewerd.sysv stop
```

Comment: For me @rinzwind aswer worked. I am using 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I am on a Xubuntu 14.04 and `sudo teamviewer --daemon disable`, which I found in another question somewhere, worked. Might want to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script "teamviewer.bash" I am using and that works in 14.04:

```
#!/bin/bash
# to be copied to /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script
# modify /usr/share/applications/teamviewer-teamviewer11.desktop :
# Exec=bash /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer.bash
# sudo visudo
# add:
# user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer
# sudo service sudo restart
echo 'teamviewer --daemon enable' | sudo sh && \
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/script/teamviewer && \
echo 'teamviewer --daemon disable' | sudo sh
```

Answer (score 1):

teamviewer is using upstart to fire up the daemon at boot. The upstart does have a respawn set to keep a process running. As a 12.04 user mentioned, respawn stanzas in the upstart script are probably what you want to comment out.

The teamviewer process is/will run as root if fired up upstart. Since the respawn is in the upstart script you could have issues killing it permanently whether you do an implicit kill or 'sudo stop teamviwer' (the upstart way) or 'sudo teamviewer --daemon status'. Your best bet is probably just to comment out respawn lines in the upstart script, then start and stop as the service as needed.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the running procceses:

```
sudo teamviewer daemon stop
```

And to prevent it from booting again:

```
sudo teamviewer daemon disable
```

*Note:* Keep in mind, this most likely stop TeamViewer from working correctly (or not at all), you may need to enable the daemon manually once you actually want to use TeamViewer.

Or remove the `teamviewer` package all together if you are not planning to use it.

Answer (score 1):

To stop Teamview daemon service

```
sudo systemctl stop teamviewerd.service
```

To remove it from startup

```
sudo systemctl disable teamviewerd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 12.04, but I do not think the process will be different using other versions of Ubuntu.

Team Viewer screen sharing is my choice to replace the now "TOO BLURRED TO READ" Skype screen share. The window sizes are about the same on my screen, but I can now read the print whereas the Skype blur makes reading impossible.

Please note that although Team Viewer runs under Wine, there are many native scripts that also run.

There has been some notice of the "TeamViewer remote control daemon" (teamviewerd) remaining active after the user is finished using and terminated teamviewer. Respawning is also used to make sure it stays active. The easiest solution is to reboot or logout after making sure the 'start with system' check box is cleared. When you log in, team viewer should not start and the daemon should not appear.

If you want a solution that does not require logging out, you must delete the respawn commands from the configuration file.

In the terminal, enter:

**gksudo gedit -s /etc/init/teamviewerd.conf**

Delete the two lines:

**respawn**

**respawn limit 5 60**

Save the file. Do not worry about the teamviewerd.conf.bak file.

Now that respawn is disabled, ending the daemon will end it. I did not notice anything unusual in the way teamviewer functions with the modified script.

Note: the changes will not initially take effect until teamviewer reads the script. Reboot, log-out, or terminate and restart teamviewer are options. I only tried log-out and it worked for me. I did not try the other options as I modified the script only once.

Comment: I am now using Ubuntu 14.04 and I just "stop" the teamviewerd process so it will no longer function until I "continue" the teamviewerd process so you can run teamviewer again. You may use gnome-system-monitor as root [gksudo gnome-system-monitor] if your version of the gnome-system-monitor does not offer to authenticate the stop or continue commands. I do not use the terminal commands, so I am unable to share them with you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have no idea what the 'teamviewerd' process does, but I found that it is required to use TeamViewer. I use the 'gnome-system-monitor' to stop the 'teamviewerd' process when I reboot and when I am finished using TeamViewer. I 'continue' the process before I start using TeamViewer.
The version I am currently using of the 'gnome-system-monitor' will ask for the authorization password when the 'stop' or 'continue' request is made. If your version of the 'gnome-system-monitor' does not ask for the authorization password and denies your request, you will need to start the 'gnome-system-monitor' in the terminal:
   gksudo gnome-system-monitor
If you are not familiar with the usage of the gnome-system-monitor, follow these suggested steps:
   select the 'Processes' tab
   select the 'teamviewerd' process
   right click and select 'Stop Process' or 'Continue Process'