# Script to close and reopen a program every hour, loop not working

Tags: bash, teamviewer

I made a script to close teamviewer and reopen it every hour. I am now testing it every 5 seconds, but the loop is simply not working. The script is running correctly, but one time only.

I need your help.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :

do

echo "hello"

killall -9 TeamViewer.exe &> sample.s

sleep 1

killall -9  teamviwerd &> sample.s

sleep 5

teamviewer &> sample.s

sleep 5

done
```

Comment: You can not kill teamviewer like this. teamviewer itself respawns when killed. You need to use the `stop` or `restart` option for the service. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/328519/why-teamviewer-keeps-running-in-the-background/328604#328604

Comment: - why do you need the sleep? (why not use `&&` and put them on 1 line?) -your 2nd killall has a typo in the name.

Comment: also, you misspelled the process name in the second killall

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is written in that loop....as long as there are no terminal errors the script should loop.

It seems though that the "done" on the last line is not executed. In that case you probably forgot to add a LF  (i.e. Enter) to the last line.