# Teamviewer Auto Start

Tags: services, teamviewer

Is there a way to make Teamviewer auto start with the Ubuntu system?

I have been on Google, but could not find a simple enough solution that I could understand.

Comment: It already should. Teamviewer, by default, will even always respawn by itself. Related (no dupe): http://askubuntu.com/questions/328519/why-teamviewer-keeps-running-in-the-background Can you check if there is a daemon in /etc/init.d for teamviewer?

Comment: There is another identical question with a full answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427125/teamviewer-does-not-start-automatically-how-do-i-make-sure-it-does

Answer (score 3):

please see the TeamViewer options:
[image]